# Value inside a double pointer isn't updated correctly (C)

Tags: c, fgets, double-pointer

I have a function that reads an input file and is supposed to modify the contents of a char** and a int*. The function is as follows:

```
void
input_parser(arguments* args, char** input, int* files) {
   char buffer[MAX];
   FILE *fr;
   fr = fopen(args->file,"r");
   if (fr == NULL) {
       printf("No correct input file was entered\n");
       exit(0);
   } 
   while(fgets(buffer,MAX,fr) != NULL) {
       input[*files] = strtok(buffer,"\n");
       (*files)++;
   }
   fclose(fr);
   return;
}
```

I have defined input and files as follows in the main program:

```
char* input[25];
files = 0;
```

I call the function as follows:

```
input_parser(args, input, &files);
```

The input file contains 3 lines as follows:

```
output1.xml
output2.xml
output3.xml
```

I notice that during the while loop the 'current' value is read correctly but stored in all input[*] resulting in:

```
input[0] = output3.xml
input[1] = output3.xml
input[2] = output3.xml
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone has any idea what is going wrong here.

Comment: The core problem is that your file reading function, as it is designed, has to concern itself with a lot of things that are not related to file handling. Since you are reading some sort of xml files, I will assume that the format and length of those files are known at compile time. Correct? If so, there is no need for dynamic memory. You should be able to allocate exactly as much memory as needed, in the form of a true 2D array in the caller. Then pass this 2D array and its sizes to the file reading function. Make sure that the function does not read out of bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is storing the address of the local variable `buffer` to each element in the `input` array: you need to copy the value returned by `strtok()`. The code as it stands is undefined behaviour as the `buffer` is out of scope once `input_parser()` returns, even it was not the logic is incorrect anyway.

If you have `strdup()`, you just use it:

```
input[*files] = strdup(strtok(buffer,"\n")); /* NULL check omitted. */
```

otherwise `malloc()` and `strcpy()`. Remember to `free()` the elements of `input` when no longer required.

Initialise `input` to be able determine which elements point to valid strings:

```
char* input[25] = { NULL };
```

Comment: Shouldn't I use strcpy than as strdup would also allocate memory even if input[x] is allready assigned as a char[25]?

Comment: I assigned '\0' to all values of input in the main but did not include that chunk in the original question. I use that in other parts to check how many elements are in there.

Comment: @BasJansen, you need to allocate memory to store the string. `input` is an array of 25 `char*`: there is nowhere to store the characters of a string directly in that array. If you are going to use `strcpy()` you _must_ allocate memory to copy into to, using `malloc()`.

Comment: I'm not really a fan of dynamic memory allocation but it does the trick. I feel a bit silly now for forgetting to not allocate memory for where input was pointing to.

Comment: @BasJansen I don't think there is a single programmer who is a fan of dynamic memory :) But it is a necessary evil in various desktop applications. As for this specific case, you might not need dynamic memory. It depends on the nature of the xml files you are reading.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to end up having danging pointers, which are pointing inside your buffer after the buffer has been deallocated.